# Laravel 5.8 , customize register controller but weirdly not working, how to solve this error?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in /home/mumildup/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 35 {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in /home/mumildup/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 35 at /home/mumildup/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php:405)

Comment: share code snippet

Comment: please share the code, but from the error message at **interface authenticatable** need parameters of some data type but you give string

Comment: Please make proper indentation of your source code and share your codes as well.

Comment: when you customize ```auth``` logic you need to implement the interface.